Is there any reason at all to use a capacitance multiplier for power rails in 2024?
I've seen a few people recommend capacitance multipliers for reducing noise on power rails recently, usually in the context of audio electronics, and I'm left feeling a bit baffled. We've got these fancy new-fangled things called LDOs, and they're really good!
As far as I can tell, an LDO is cheaper, smaller, simpler, requires far less design work and parts sourcing, has lower dropout (hence the name), can be more efficient as a result of the low dropout, actually produces a constant output voltage rather than just tracking the valleys of the input rail minus a diode drop, has a far lower impedance output (so less rail sag/noise as a result of varying load), has way better PSRR in general, and comes with the added bonus of easily offering extra features like fold-back protection. Modern capacitors are also very high density and very low impedance compared to the 1960s, which is the era I associate the capacitance multiplier with.
Despite this, I still keep seeing people talking about them. Audio folks are known to have perculiar tastes in electronics, so maybe it's more about style than substance, but it leaves me mightily confused. What am I missing? Do discrete capacitance multipler circuits have any properties at all that render them superior to a modern LDO in the context of voltage regulation? (Please bring receipts if you have an example!)

can you clarify why you are mixing up a capacitance (multiplier) with LDOs? They are not interchangeable in general - is the only use of capacitance multipliers in PDNs? Moreover, for voltage smoothing, LDOs might be unsuitable for the voltages/currents that are needed in a high power audio amp - or any audio power application for that matter. Did you consider this?
Forgive my tone if it seems harsh - I am just trying to better understand your point/question ;)

Can an LDO be used for a 20W (or higher) Class-AB audio power amplifier?

"is the only use of capacitance multipliers in PDNs?" - of course not. That's why I constrained the question to the specific context of PDNs, which is where I'd seen them recommended. Similarly, if I had asked "is there any reason to use an opamp output as a power supply" I wouldn't expect the fact that opamps can be used for other things to be relevant. That'd be weird. Regarding high voltage / current capability, if that is a genuine reason to use a discrete capacitance multiplier, and you can provide details to that effect, then that would be a good answer to post.

@RohatKılıç Sure, why not? High voltage LDOs are pretty cheap these days, and if you need more current you can use an external BJT while still retaining vastly superior noise and voltage regulation properties, as per this article from Analog. There's also an argument to be made that modern switching converters are more than sufficiently quiet for audio stuff, if you design them well, but that's getting off-topic for this question.

Certainly there are applications where high PSRR is more important than load regulation and current requirements are modest. Why not use a more complex $10 ultra-high PSRR LDO instead of a $0.05 capacitance multiplier, just to get a poorer performance in that one metric? Does that extend to audio (other than perhaps some transformerless preamp applications)? I doubt it.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Could you provide an example where a capacitance multiplier with a BOM cost of $0.05 has a uniquely high performance that can only be matched by an LDO costing $10 or more? That seems like it would be a good counter-example.

@Polynomial They come recommended by Phil Hobbs for biasing low-noise cascode front ends, with typical >100dB PSRR using a super-beta transistor and RC. Compare with an LT3045, say, with 76dB PSRR (minimum). Most regulators don't give you a PSRR vs. frequency graph, PSRR is specified at DC. Also varies with the headroom.

Low drop out is only useful and efficient if you genuinely need it, i.e. your input voltage is very close to the output you want and doesn't sag under load.

@Polynomial if you feel like setting up a realistic Laplace domain polynomial fraction for a practical capacitance multiplier and want to compare it with a model of a mid-90s state-of-the-art LDO, Gabriel Alfonso Rincon-Mora's PhD thesis might be of interest. Also, bold font choice!

PNP common emitter in LDO is much slower than NPN in voltage follower (multiplier) , so PNP passes lower frequency noise that NPN multiplier activelly filters.
Also, LDO contain few stages of transistors what decrease the reaction time to noise disturbance.

hm, the LDO architectures I find seem (it's rarely stated by manufacturers) to be complementary MOS, not single-sided BJT designs. (I mean, sure, things like LM317 exist, but I'd argue that's something from that generation is not an LDO by modern standards)
